# QML use C ++ function with parameters

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I was using widgets in my application, but I am migrating to qml because of the appearance but I intend to continue using C ++ in the banckground

```
class Usuario : public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool login WRITE login)

public:

    Usuario(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Usuario();

    static bool login(const QString& usuario, const QString& senha);

};
```

When compiling I get an error indicating that the function does not receive any arguments, so how can I call the login function in qml?

Comment: Please provide a full (minimal) example and remember that Qt offers several methods to integrate C++ with QML.

Comment: @sirop If I knew how to do that I wouldn't be asking how to call a c ++ function with parameters in a qml script, this video does it but as I said in the post there are errors when adding parameters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e35ugcY2aOk&t

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing concepts, Q_PROPERTY does not serve to expose functions or methods but to create a property (more information [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)), what you should use is Q_INVOKABLE or Q_SLOT:

```
class Usuario : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Usuario(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Usuario();
    Q_INVOKABLE static bool login(const QString& usuario, const QString& senha);
    // or
    // Q_SLOT static bool login(const QString& usuario, const QString& senha);
};
```

Comment: I tried to use Q_INVOKABLE, this time it was recognized as a function in the qml script, compiled, but when executed I get the following error: TypeError: Property 'login' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: @IvesTI provide a [mre]

Comment: usuario.hpp: https://pastebin.com/HhqpYdyU login.qml: https://pastebin.com/uzkdXxDY

Comment: @IvesTI If you want help then provide an MRE, those 2 codes are not(please read the link), plus they must be in your question not in external links.

Comment: The first time I tried the stackoverflow it didn't allow because there was a lot of code in the question so I had to post it in pastebin